# Developing a maze generator without openGL in Qt, C++

Tags: c++, qt, view, graphics

I'm new to Qt and wonder how it is possible to generate a maze with Qt? If so, how do I even start?

If it were just pure coding in C++, I could just simply start with declaring my 2D array and carry on with coding the maze.

For this project, everything must be in a GUI version so it means changing the 2D array into GUI. I simply have no idea where to start.

What I do know is, since this is in GUI, I have to start with `QGraphicsView` in Qt. Then what? Do I create a 2D array from there? Even if I create a 2D array, how am I going to fit it inside the `QGraphicsView`? Am I going the right direction? Can anyone give me a rough guideline?

Current Implementation Trial for mazewidget.h

```
#ifndef MAZEWIDGET_H
#define MAZEWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "ui_mazewidget.h"
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

class MazeWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MazeWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MazeWidget();
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void setVec(QList<QList<bool>> const& vec);

private:
    Ui::MazeWidget ui;
    QList<QList<bool>> vec_;
};

#endif // MAZEWIDGET_H
```

and mazewidget.cpp

```
#include "mazewidget.h"
#include "mazeapplication.h"
#include "ui_mazeapplication.h"

MazeWidget::MazeWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

MazeWidget::~MazeWidget()
{

}

void MazeApplication::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    QPixmap pixmap(vec_.front().size(), vec_.size()); // pixmap with scale 1:1
    QPainter pixmap_painter(&pixmap);

    for (int y = 0; y < vec_.size(); y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < vec_[y].size(); x++)
        {
        pixmap_painter.setPen(vec_[y][x] ? QColor("white") : QColor("black"));
        pixmap_painter.drawPoint(x, y); // Draw individual pixels
        }

    QPainter painter(this);
    QPixmap pixmap_scaled = pixmap.scaled(size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio); // scale to fit the widget
    painter.drawPixmap(
        (width() - pixmap_scaled.width()) / 2,
        (height() - pixmap_scaled.height()) / 2,
        pixmap_scaled.width(), pixmap_scaled.height(), pixmap_scaled); // draw with alignment in the middle
}

void setVec(QList<QList<bool>> const& vec)
{
    vec_ = vec;
    // You can pre-paint pixmaps here, if you keep vec_ as value or make a function and keep it updated.
}
```

Comment: Do you want the walls have the same width as corridors?

Comment: Yep, they should all be the same

Comment: Do all mazes have same size?

Comment: Up to user definition

Comment: Now, at what line do you get the error?

Comment: I found the problem on the second glance. What's `MazeApplication::` have to do before `paintEvent` ? It's got to be `MazeWidget::`, which is missing before `setVec` too. You also don't need `#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>`. Future advice: don't `#include <QtGui>
#include <QtCore>` when you don't need to (just for tests) and `#include` only necessary classes.

Comment: Well, does it work out for you?

Comment: @LogicStuff Hi Logic, I'm really sorry I am on some other projects currently, once I am done I will definitely get back to you, thanks alot.

Comment: @LogicStuff Is there any way I can reach you personally? I might need some more help . :)

Comment: My email in my profile.

Comment: @LogicStuff Can't find it, in the meantime, thank you.

Comment: Gonna mark the question as ticked because help is given within. Thank you for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `QGraphicsView` to draw rectangles. It's simpler to subclass `QWidget` and override `paintEvent`.

```
class MazeWidget : public QWidget
{
public:
    MazeWidget(QWidget *parent = 0) :
        QWidget(parent)
    {
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
    {
        QPixmap pixmap(vec_.front().size(), vec_.size()); // pixmap with scale 1:1
        QPainter pixmap_painter(&pixmap);

        for(int y = 0; y < vec_.size(); y++)
            for(int x = 0; x < vec_[y].size(); x++)
            {
                pixmap_painter.setPen(vec_[y][x] ? QColor("white") : QColor("black"));
                pixmap_painter.drawPoint(x, y); // Draw individual pixels
            }

        QPainter painter(this);
        QPixmap pixmap_scaled = pixmap.scaled(size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio); // scale to fit the widget
        painter.drawPixmap(
            (width() - pixmap_scaled.width()) / 2,
            (height() - pixmap_scaled.height()) / 2,
            pixmap_scaled.width(), pixmap_scaled.height(), pixmap_scaled); // draw with alignment in the middle
    }

    void setVec(QList<QList<bool>> const& vec)
    {
        vec_ = vec;
        // You can pre-paint pixmaps here, if you keep vec_ as value or make a function and keep it updated.
    }

private:
    QList<QList<bool>> vec_; // Consider using reference or pointer
};
```

This might be not the most efficient approach, but works nice if you only need two colors.

Comment: Hi LogicStuff, I'm sorry I dont understand the code at all. Is there any way you can explain them to me?

And, I tried implementing the above code and it doesn't work lol.

Comment: @Newbie Did you actually instantiate the class?

Comment: Hi LogicStuff, I can't seem to implement the vec

Comment: Undeclared Identifier, which i already did include it in my header file

Comment: @Newbie is vec_ the identifier?

Comment: Yes it is, which I already declared it in the header file, but it says there as undeclared.

Comment: @Newbie So you divided declaration and definition among .h and .cpp?

Comment: @Newbie Add your files to the question, or give me a link to some repository.

Comment: Hi, I've changed the question, please take a look, thank you.

Comment: Hi, at the first line of paintEvent, QPixmap pixmap(vec_.front().size(), vec_.size()); and in the setvec method. Both shows vec_ as undeclaredidentifier

Comment: I'm going to bed now, will wake up to look at your reply later on, thanks so much. :)